# AmEng: Is the T tapped (flap) in the compound noun heart attack?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, consonants, connected-speech

Is the T tapped (flap) in the compound noun: *hear**t** attack*? I'm talking about the T in the word "heart".

Answer (score 4):

The /t/ in *heart* will become a voiced tap in the string  *heart attack* for many speakers of American Englishes. This means that the compound nouns *heart attack* and *hard attack* will be homophones. The /d/ in *hard attack* will also become a tap in this position for many speakers.

Syllable final /t/ is liable to become a tap for such speakers when at the end of a syllable and surrounded by vowels, or if preceding a vowel and following a voiced sonorant, in other words after a nasal or the liquid, /r/.

[In case anyone is wondering what a *hard attack* is, it's when we use a glottal stop before a word beginning with a vowel!]

Comment: Hard atTACK.    HEART attack.  Usually.

Comment: @TRomano If *hard* was a real adjective here that is indeed what you'd get. But it isn't here though, it's part of a compound noun. Compare *a greenhouse* with *a green house*, or *I'm going to the white house* with *I'm going to the  White House*!

Comment: @TRomano Or a jacket which is burning, a smoking jacket, with a type of jacket for smoking in: a smoking jacket :)

Comment: I wasn't clear.  I was saying that the accent falls differently. What we need in the second half is a hard atTACK, said the football coach. He has suffered a HEART attack.

Comment: @TRomano No, you were clear:) What I'm saying is that the compound noun *hard attack* has stress on the first word and not the second. The adjective noun combination *hard attack* as per your example is stressed on both words, with the second being more prominent. Hence my parallel examples with "**White** House" versus "white **house**", where the first is a compound with stress on the first word only, but the second is an adjective plus noun which therefore has stress on both words.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the compound noun *hard attack*".  **Heart-attack** is the compound, right?

Comment: @TRomano It isn't usually hyphenated, but it's the phonetic term described in my last paragraph in brackets. Zoltan, who's a phonetics enthusiast, accidentally used it in his original title instead of *heart attack*. It's definitely because of the phonetics term :)

Comment: I do agree that "heart attack" is a dactyl.